# como crear un jar de java

Tags: java, cmd

cordial saludos amigos. tengo problemas al intentar crear un ejecutable jar desde el simbolo del sistema, despues de hacer todo el proceso del empaquetado y al correr el programa (java -jar Systema.jar)

me aparece el siguiente error:

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MainCoke has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

```
´´public class MainCoke{
public static void main(String[] Holger){
Coke coke=new Coke("Welcome",350,450);
coke.setVisible(true);
coke.setResizable(false);
}
}´´
```

Answer (score 1):

Bien, el mensaje de error es claro: Estas intentando ejecutar el `.jar` con un **JRE** mas reciente. **Es como que lo compiles con Java 11 y lo ejecutes con Java 8.**

> **DOS OPCIONES**

1- Compilar el `.jar` en una versión mas vieja/nueva dependiendo tus necesidades.

2- Ejecutarlo con un JRE mas viejo/nuevo.

[Este sitio web](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-unsupportedclassversion) te puede ayudar brindándote mas soluciones y/o pasos para una instalación menos reciente de la JRE.

Saludos.